# Highcharts: areasplinerange with fill color that takes account of direction of range

Tags: highcharts

I would like to fill a space between two lines that generally move up and down in tandem, but sometimes one is above the other, and sometimes the other way.  And I'd like the fill color to reflect which line is on top.

Take [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xczdfkjf/1/) as an example.  Where the lower and upper ends of the range cross over, between 6 Jul and 7 Jul, I'd like the fill colour to change.  Is this possible?

```
$(function () {

    var ranges = [
            [1246406400000, 14.3, 27.7],
            [1246492800000, 14.5, 27.8],
            [1246579200000, 15.5, 28.6],
            [1246665600000, 16.7, 28.7],
            [1246752000000, 16.5, 25.0],
            [1246838400000, 17.8, 22.7],
            // low-high becomes high-low here
            [1246924800000, 20.8, 19.5],
            [1247011200000, 21.4, 17.5],
            [1247097600000, 23.8, 15.2],
            [1247184000000, 21.8, 14.6],
            [1247270400000, 23.7, 13.7],
            [1247356800000, 23.3, 13.0],
            [1247443200000, 23.7, 12.6],
            [1247529600000, 20.7, 12.8]
        ]


    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        title: {
            text: 'Cross-over'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },

        legend: {
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Range',
            data: ranges,
            type: 'areasplinerange',
            lineWidth: 0,
            linkedTo: ':previous',
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            fillOpacity: 0.3,
            zIndex: 0
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: You can define a zone array for an x axis which the value is the cross point. http://jsfiddle.net/86xdxn8a/

Comment: @morganfree: the tricky bit would be working out where the lines cross, in the case of a spline!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using this mathematical concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection but it works only for straight lines, so if you want to use it, you will have to change the type of your chart from areasplinerange to arearange.

JS function that checks intersection coordinates:

```
function checkLineIntersection(a1, a2) {
  if (a1 && a2) {
    var saX = a2.x - a1.x,
      saY = a2.high - a1.high,
      sbY = a2.low - a1.low,
      sabX = a1.plotX - a2.plotX,
      sabY = a1.high - a1.low,
      u,
      t;


    u = (-saY * sabX + saX * sabY) / (-saX * saY + saX * sbY);
    t = (saX * sabY - sbY * sabX) / (-saX * saY + saX * sbY);

    if (u >= 0 && u <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1) {
      return {
        plotX: a1.x + (t * saX),
        plotY: a1.high + (t * saY)
      };
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

And Highcharts approach to calculate the zones and properly update series:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load() {
      let chart = this,
        series = chart.series[0],
        data = series.data,
        cross,
        negative = true,
        howManyIntersections = 0,
        zones = [];

      data.forEach((point, i) => {
        if (point.low > point.high && negative) {
          howManyIntersections++;
          negative = !negative;
          cross = checkLineIntersection(data[i - 1], point)
          zones.push({
            value: cross.plotX,
            fillColor: 'red'
          })
        } else if (point.low < point.high && !negative) {
          howManyIntersections++;
          negative = !negative;
          cross = checkLineIntersection(data[i - 1], point)
          zones.push({
            value: cross.plotX,
            fillColor: 'green'
          })
        }
      })

      if (howManyIntersections % 2) {
        zones.push({
          fillColor: 'green'
        })
      } else {
        zones.push({
          fillColor: 'red'
        })
      }

      series.update({
        zones: zones
      })

    }
  }
},
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0qzsm83j

I've got the power!